# E4 MTrimmedWindow is out of sync with Shell

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I found that E4 model does not synchronize widget status

e.g.

shell.getVisible() == false

But the model is true

My understanding is that the E4 model will not listen to the SWT.Show and SWT.Hide events of Control. If you directly set the visible of control, the E4 model will not be updated synchronously

I'm not sure if my understanding is correct. I'm still learning E4

Comment: The MUIELement.isVisible method is actually nothing to do with the visibility of the Shell, it has some weird internal meaning, just ignore it. It is not something you ever use in normal e4 code.

Comment: E4 source code is hard to read, no documentation :(

Comment: Indeed, that is why I am not absolutely sure exactly what it is for, but as I said, just leave it as true and ignore it. The `isToBeRendered` setting is more useful, that controls if the part should be shown or not.

Comment: @natarol You are welcome to change this. Nowadays it's just a pull request on GitHub. ;)

Comment: @howlger ok...I need to study how to contribute correctly